# Adapting PinTintColor to Ray Wenderlich tutorial for mapkit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit

I'm using a tutorial for building my first app. http://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial

Ive searched for pintintcolor but nothing comes up.

Basically the tutorial uses this code to set the color

```
// pinColor for disciplines: Sculpture, Plaque, Mural, Monument, other
func pinColor() -> MKPinAnnotationColor{
    switch discipline {
    case "Sculpture", "Plaque":
        return .Red
    case "Mural", "Monument":
        return .Purple
    default:
        return .Green
```

The trouble is this is what apple has on the developers site

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_11/Swift/MapKit.html

Modified MKPinAnnotationView
Declaration

From:

```
class MKPinAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView {
    var pinColor: MKPinAnnotationColor
    var animatesDrop: Bool
}
```

To:

```
class MKPinAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView {
    class func redPinColor() -> NSColor
    class func greenPinColor() -> NSColor
    class func purplePinColor() -> NSColor
    var pinTintColor: NSColor!
    var animatesDrop: Bool
    var pinColor: MKPinAnnotationColor
}
```

The Ray Wenderlich tutorial is setup a fair bit different so I don't quite understand how to set it up the same way as it. I have tried a few different configurations but I can't get it to work.

Any help appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of use property pinColor (deprecated), use property pinTintColor (iOS9)

```
//view.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColor.Green

view.pinTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()

//UIColor functions
public class func blackColor() -> UIColor // 0.0 white 
public class func darkGrayColor() -> UIColor // 0.333 white 
public class func lightGrayColor() -> UIColor // 0.667 white 
public class func whiteColor() -> UIColor // 1.0 white 
public class func grayColor() -> UIColor // 0.5 white 
public class func redColor() -> UIColor // 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 RGB 
public class func greenColor() -> UIColor // 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 RGB 
public class func blueColor() -> UIColor // 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 RGB 
public class func cyanColor() -> UIColor // 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 RGB 
public class func yellowColor() -> UIColor // 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 RGB 
public class func magentaColor() -> UIColor // 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 RGB 
public class func orangeColor() -> UIColor // 1.0, 0.5, 0.0 RGB 
public class func purpleColor() -> UIColor // 0.5, 0.0, 0.5 RGB 
public class func brownColor() -> UIColor // 0.6, 0.4, 0.2 RGB 
public class func clearColor() -> UIColor // 0.0 white, 0.0 alpha
```

Here the full picture:

```
import MapKit

class MyAnnotation: MKAnnotation, NSObject 
{
    let identifier: String
    let title: String?
    let subtitle: String?
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(identifier: String, title: String, subtitle: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)
    {
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.coordinate = coordinate

        super.init()
    }

    func mapItem() -> MKMapItem
    {
        let addressDictionary = [String(CNPostalAddressStreetKey): self.subtitle!]
        let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: self.coordinate, addressDictionary: addressDictionary)

        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        mapItem.name = self.title

        return mapItem
    }
}


func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
{
    if let annotation = annotation as? MyAnnotation
    {
        let identifier = annotation.identifier
        var view = MKPinAnnotationView()

        if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier) as! MKPinAnnotationView!
        {
            view = dequeuedView
            view.annotation = annotation
        }
        else
        {
            view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            view.animatesDrop = true
            view.canShowCallout = true

            switch identifier 
            {
                case "Sculpture", "Plaque":
                    view.pinTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
                case "Mural", "Monument":
                    view.pinTintColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
                default:
                    view.pinTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            }
        }
        return view
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: So I tried this instead of what I originally wrote

    // pinColor for disciplines: Sculpture, Plaque, Mural, Monument, other
    func pinTintColor() -> UIColor{
        switch discipline {
        case "Sculpture", "Plaque":
            return .grayColor()
        case "Mural", "Monument":
            return .purpleColor()
        default:
            return .orangeColor()

It gets no errors but it doesnt change the color of the pins?

Comment: Got it working, forgot to change pincolor to pinTintColor in VCMapView. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, good luck. Don't forget to vote on arrow up in my post =)

Answer (score 6):

Incase anyone else is following the tutorial and is seeing the following error: "'MKPinAnnotationColor' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use MKPinAnnotationView's pinTintColor instead"

Simply update the pinColor routine to return a UIColor instead.

```
func pinColor() -> UIColor  {
    switch discipline {
    case "Sculpture", "Plaque":
        return UIColor.redColor()
    case "Mural", "Monument":
        return UIColor.purpleColor()
    default:
        return UIColor.greenColor()
    }
}
```

And then make the corresponding call to set the pinTintColor like so:

```
  view.pinTintColor = annotation.pinColor()
```